# Mysterious output from Lua after modifying a control

Tags: lua, wxwidgets

I am using Lua with wxLua to build a GUI. Normally when I exit the app, I get no output from Lua.

However I just added a function to a wxListView (called myListView) like this

```
myListView.foo = bar

function bar (self)
    -- do something with the wxListView
end
```

Whether or not I ever called foo(), when I exit the app, I get the following output from Lua:

```
~wxLuaObject -2 1 0
```

If I comment out the assignment, I get no output when exiting the app. If instead, I nil out foo later on in the code:

```
myListView.foo = nil
```

I get the same output immediately when that line is executed and then again on program exit.

What does the output mean? What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I may be missing what you are trying to do. I tried the following code and it works fine (my message is printed, and no other messages are printed): `listCtrl = wx.wxListView(panel, ID_LISTCTRL, wx.wxDefaultPosition, wx.wxDefaultSize); listCtrl.foo = function() print "something" end; listCtrl.foo()`. This is on Windows. What platform are you on?

Comment: @Paul - Thanks for the response! It is Win 7 64-bit. I don't know if it could explain my result, but I neglected to mention that I am using an xrc file for the gui layout. I run the program using "lua.exe myApp.lua" from a command line prompt, and when it exits I get the mysterious message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an internal diagnostic for the case when wxLuaObject is destroyed and `m_reference == LUA_NOREF` (-2 as it is in your case) and Lua state object is not in closing state (0 as reported in your case):

```
// this is from modules/wxlua/src/wxlbind.cpp (starts on line 83 in my version)
wxLuaObject::~wxLuaObject()
{
    if ((m_reference != LUA_NOREF) && m_wxlState->Ok() && !m_wxlState->IsClosing())
    {
        m_wxlState->wxluaR_Unref(m_reference, &wxlua_lreg_refs_key);
        m_reference = LUA_NOREF;
    }
    //else if (!m_wxlState->IsClosing())
    //    wxPrintf(wxT("~wxLuaObject %d %d %d\n"), (int)m_reference, (int)m_wxlState->Ok(), (int)m_wxlState->IsClosing());
```

I have this message commented out in my wxlua code (2.8.12.1), but you may want to check your version and upgrade as needed. This is the only place where `~wxLuaObject` message appears in the source code. It seems to be harmless, but it can potentially point to other issues with what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you! I will be less hesitant to dig into the source code next time :)